# How to iterate through part of the positional arguments in a command procedure in bash?

Tags: bash, command, arguments, procedure

I have written a command procedure that takes 12 positional arguments. How can i iterate only through the first 10 (for example). If i use `shift [n]`, then argument $0 comes in but I don't want to use it.
Can I use something like list comprehension?:

```
for arg in [$1..$10]
do 
   echo $arg
done
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag.

Comment: I am writing a command procedure, which i compile with `bash name arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter expansion like so:

```
for i in "${@:1:10}"; do
   echo "$i"
done
```

For more info, see `man bash` -> `Parameter Expansion` -> `Substring Expansion`

Comment: Please use double-quotes (`"${@:1:10}"` and `echo "$i"`) to avoid problems with funny characters (spaces, wildcards, etc) in the arguments.